# Design a Plugin-architecture

Tags: dart, dart-isolates

May someone give us all an approach-outline for designing a plugin-architecture core in Dart.

How would it be possible in Dart to add, update and remove plugins in the running application core?

Some answers are already given in the discussion groups of Dart - https://groups.google.com/a/dartlang.org/forum/#!topic/misc/O3BA_9FXcp4.

I move the thread here, because stackoverflow is more appropriate for questions like this.

Answer (score 1):

My initial thought is that each plug-in would run inside its own isolate, which would require a well-defined protocol that the plug-in would conform to in order to interact with the main application isolate.  Ideally, the nitty-gritty details of the protocol would hidden behind a nice API that plug-in developers would use.